# Data Structures and Algorithms - Recursion question, why vector variable is used to store recursion call

Tags: c++

I've just started recursion and got one doubt,

This is the code,

```cpp
vector<string> printNTimes(int n) {

    vector<string> arr;
    
    if(n>0){
        arr=printNTimes(n - 1);
        arr.push_back("Recursion");
        }
    return arr;
}
```

Can anyone explain, why we stored `printNTimes(n - 1)` in `arr`, when its already vector storing "Recursion".

Even if it can be done in a better way, I wanna understand why it's working this way too. :)

Comment: Step through with a debugger and all will become clear.

Comment: The function stores "Recursion" *once* into the vector. Where does the other n - 1 copies come from?

Comment: Please read the tags you are using. The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`, and your question has nothing to do with this. By not using the correct tags, your question was not viewed by the appropriate audience. You should have tagged `c++`

Comment: Right before `arr=printNTimes(n - 1);` line, `arr` is an empty vector. What do you mean, its already vector storing "Recursion"? Print its size at that point, see for yourself.

Comment: Lemma: for any non-negative `k`, `printNTimes(k)` returns a vector of `k` elements, all equal to the string `"Recursion"`. [Proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The call to function `printNTimes` is the recursion. The call to function `arr.pushback` adds an element to the local `arr`. It does not cause recursion.

Recursion happens when a function calls itself. It also occurs when a chain of function calls leads back to the beginning of the chain, e.g., function `a` calls `b`, `b` calls `c`, and then `c` calls `a`.

You can see what is happening by adding some output to function `printNTimes`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void put_vector(std::vector<std::string> const& arr)
{
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < arr.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "arr[" << i << "] : " << arr[i] << '\n';
    std::cout.put('\n');
}

std::vector<std::string> printNTimes(int n)
{
    // Add some output, so you can follow the recursion:
    std::cout << "(Entering) n: " << n << "\n\n";

    std::vector<std::string> arr;

    if (n > 0) {
        arr = printNTimes(n - 1);
        arr.push_back("Recursion");
    }

    // Add some output, so you can follow the recursion:
    std::cout << "(Exiting) n: " << n << '\n';
    put_vector(arr);
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    printNTimes(3);
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
(Entering) n: 3

(Entering) n: 2

(Entering) n: 1

(Entering) n: 0

(Exiting) n: 0

(Exiting) n: 1
arr[0] : Recursion

(Exiting) n: 2
arr[0] : Recursion
arr[1] : Recursion

(Exiting) n: 3
arr[0] : Recursion
arr[1] : Recursion
arr[2] : Recursion
```

You can remove the (recursive) call to function `printNTimes` by commenting it out.

```cpp
        //arr = printNTimes(n - 1);
```

Now, all you get is this:

```
(Entering) n: 3

(Exiting) n: 3
arr[0] : Recursion
```

You would also see this if you single-stepped the execution in your debugger.